# MongoDB - Search string for an element from an array of words

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

How do i check if a string contains a list of words from an array. I know how do it with one word however how do with an array?

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
db.getCollection('questions').find( {$text:{$search:{$in: ['chips', 'mars']} }}  )
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db.getCollection('questions').find( {$text:{$search:"chips mars" }}  )`
to find questions with either "chips" or "mars" or both.

`db.getCollection('questions').find( {$text:{$search:"\"chips\" \"mars\"" }}  )`
to find questions with both "chips" and "mars".

[Docs for text index search reads](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#search-field):

> $search is a string of terms that MongoDB parses and uses to query the text index. MongoDB performs a logical OR search of the terms unless specified as a phrase.

Comment: Ah ok, i just need a space between words?

Comment: Yes, I have added a quote from the docs to the answer to make it crystal clear.